# GWT add double click handler only for table rows, not header

Tags: java, gwt, double-click

We have implemented a GWT custom table widget in our application by extending `com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Composite`. There is a double click handler on this table, that opens up a popup to edit the selected record.

```
// 'table' is our implementation

final NoSelectionModel<OurCustomDTOClass> editSelectedRowModel = new NoSelectionModel<OurCustomDTOClass>();
table.getTable().setSelectionModel(editSelectedRowModel, DefaultSelectionEventManager.createBlacklistManager(0));
table.addDomHandler(new DoubleClickHandler() {
        @Override
        public void onDoubleClick(final DoubleClickEvent event) {
            // code to open the popup to edit the record        
            // this popup must be opened only if the user selects the rows and NOT the header   
        }
}, DoubleClickEvent.getType());
```

Just for more information, the table is painted as `th` (for table headers) and `tr` (for table rows).

What we need to do is avoid double click action if the user double clicks the table header. I have searched on the SO and other references but no luck yet.

Any useful pointers are appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try checking the target of the event:

```
Element e = Element.as(event.getNativeEvent().getEventTarget());
if (e.getTagName().toLowerCase().equals("td")) {
    // do something
}
```

Or you can split your widget into two separate widgets - one for the header, and another one for the table body.